# Heroku error: Cannot find module 'nodemailer-smtp-transport'

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, package.json, nodemailer

I have tried to find the answer for this already but even if I use the response for similar issues it won't work.

Full log on heroku [image]

[image]
Here is my node.js code

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000,function() {
    console.log("App is running" );
});




app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); app.use(bodyParser.json());


/*app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("App is running on port " + port);
});*/

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
  service: 'Gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'naomikudren@gmail.com',
    pass: '###'
  }
}));

app.post('/send-email', function(req, res) {
    var mailOptions = {
        from: '"Naomi" <naomikudren@gmail.com>', // sender address
        to: "naomikudren@gmail.com", // list of receivers
        subject: 'Request ', // Subject line
        text: "From: " + req.body.from + " To: " + req.body.to + " Date: " + req.body.date + " Time: " + req.body.time // plaintext body

    };
        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
         if (error) {
             return console.log(error);
         }
         console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
     });

     res.redirect("/index.html");
 });
```

Is there anything in my code that I am missing or what could be causing my server not to run?

Comment: The error is caused by some different unhandled error mentioned higher in your logs - the one you pasted here is just its consequence. Could you please provide more of the logs, where thrown error starts?

Comment: That is the full log.

Comment: And there is nothing above `at Object.module._extension (...)` part? Try running `heroku logs --tail` and scrolling up.

Comment: Found it, it seems to not find 'nodemailer-smtp-transport' but it is definitely there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I pointed out in comments before, the error you mentioned is only the consequence of previously encountered error preventing your app from starting.

> (...) Boot timeout

It basically means, that process starting your app has timed out because of different reason.

In this case, it cannot find module `nodemailer-smtp-transport`, so all you need to do is to provide it as property of `dependencies` inside your `package.json` file and heroku should take care of the rest.

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.4",
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if your app is working fine on your local machine doesn't guarantee that it will run on heroku as well.

In case heroku gives you an error of 'module not found', the first thing you should check if your **package.json** file.

**Solution**

If you find that your module is not present as dependency inside package.json than following the given steps

```
npm install <your missing package>
git add .
git commit -m "my fix"
git push heroku master
```

Note: you may update the push command according to your branch, in my case it was master.